# package puppet ensure => purged without output

Tags: package, puppet

I know there is a bug in puppet for removing a package option like

```
package {'foo': ensure => purged}
```

and it will execute

```
/usr/bin/yum -y erase foo
```

but there is any way to purge without showing like below when I am executing `puppet agent --test`?

```
Notice: /Stage[main]/Php/Package[foo]/ensure: created
```

I can't use option absent because I need to be purged if it is present.

Comment: Are you asking how to suppress Puppet reporting on resources during agent execution?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it would be possible, but most likely you don't want to do that. The code above is "the correct way".

The notice `Notice: /Stage[main]/Php/Package[foo]/ensure: created` only tells you that some resource has been declared in Puppet catalog (which doesn't mean that the package is installed).

You can check the declaration from terminal:

```
$ puppet resource package foo

package { 'foo':
  ensure => 'purged',
}
```

which ensures that the package will be purged if present. A that's probably what you want.